# BC639 16 exploding on custom design

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, comparator, phototransistor, schmitt-trigger

On a board I designed, a transistor, BC639 16, is exploding.

A pinball machine has one board that has some design flaws. Its schematics are these:[image]

[image]

This PCB has 8 optos (QVE11233.0086) that are integrated into a switch matrix with the 8 being in different rows and all of them in the same column. These optos are obsolete and also have a notable delay in showing their status making the CPU of the pinball machine think the optos are broken.

Well, I redesigned it this way:
[image]

In this case instead of having the optos directly in the switch matrix, the optos are kept on constantly and use comparators to connect to the matrix with a schmitt trigger. Also leds 1 through 8 are there to indicate about the status in the optos and for diagnostics.

The problem is that whenever the 12 Volts are fed into the PCB, the transistor Q1 explodes. In the schematics it is shown as bc637 but I used a BC639 16, and if I'm not mistaken, there shouldn't be a problem since voltages are below breakdown. Does anyone see any issue with the design?

Also, in case it helps, the schematics for the pinball system are these: https://arcarc.xmission.com/Pinball/PDF%20Pinball%20Misc/Williams%20WPC%20Schematic%20manual.pdf They pcb is connected to the CPU board (shown on page 4) with the rows being connector J205 and columns being J206.

Thanks!

Comment: Connect a multimeter measuring amps at the collector and emitter of the transistor pads. I bet there are amps flowing or at least several hundred mA due to R5 being the wrong value.

Comment: Will give it a try although I don't think that's the issue. The 12 V supplied to the playfield are fused (3 A) The fuse was not blown, not even after it exploded, and it is the correct value since I replaced it myself not so long ago.

Comment: You have checked everything so there is no rational reason for it. Therefore your board must be haunted!

Answer (score 0):

One of the negative inputs to one of the LM339 is possibly shorted to the positive power supply. I am assuming it worked then just failed. There is a possibility that line is shorted to +. The other possibility I see is R5 is shorted to +.

Comment: All the testing is being done on a PCB from JLC with the design exactly matching the schematics therefore there are no mistakes between what is seen on the schematics and the actual circuit so I guess no unwanted shorts. Also checked with the DMM that no shorts were made soldering. Only short is between the emitter and collector of the transistor after it exploded. There is something wrong around the transistor. Idk if it is the transistor itself or what, since this is a BC639 16 and what I originally intended to use was BC637 or BC639.

Comment: Is it possible your pads for the device are wrong. I had that happen to me on my first PCB. I now check them and do not flip them.